# Ошибка конвертации при запросе insert

Tags: c#, sql

Есть таблица с данными, хочу туда добавить новую строку.
Но  дословно возникает такая ошибка.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '???????? ?????? ' to data type smallint."
```

Данные берутся из текстового массива и записываются в таблицу в базе данных. Сама таблица выглядит так.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[METHODNAME] (
    [METHODID]        SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION]     NVARCHAR (250) NULL,
    [TEXTDESCRIPTION] NVARCHAR (250) NULL,
    [METHODTYPEID]    TINYINT        NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_METHODNAME] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([METHODID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_METHODNAME_METHODTYPEID] FOREIGN KEY ([METHODTYPEID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[METHODTYPES] ([METHODTYPEID]) NOT FOR REPLICATION
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iMETHODTYPEID_METHODNAME]
    ON [dbo].[METHODNAME]([METHODTYPEID] ASC);
```

Вот так в программе я это делаю.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connextionstring ="Integrated Security=SSPI;Pooling=false;Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=Solution21";
            string[] words = new[] {"1058", "ПНД Ф 12.16.1", "ПНД Ф 12.16.1", ""};

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connextionstring))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var a = Int16.Parse(words[0]);
                var b = words[1];
                var с = words[2];
              //  var d = words[3];
                SqlCommand command19 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO METHODNAME ( METHODID , DESCRIPTION, TEXTDESCRIPTION) VALUES (@a, @b,@c)",
                    connection);
                command19.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
                command19.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b);
                command19.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", с);
              //  command19.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", d);
                command19.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос как избавиться от этой ошибки?
Пробовал команду писать так.

```
 command19.Parameters.Add("@a",SqlDbType.SmallInt);
 command19.Parameters["@a"].Value = a;
 command19.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.NVarChar,250);
 command19.Parameters["@b"].Value = b;
 command19.Parameters.Add("@c", SqlDbType.NVarChar,250);
 command19.Parameters["@c"].Value = с;
```

Comment: Используйте другой метод создания параметров, и укажите тип параметра явно - тогда с# не будет конвертировать тип как ему вздумается. Я с глюком AddWithValue сталкивался. Делайте Add и заполняйте два поля в параметре: тип и значение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а можно пример такой конструкции? Вместо  AddWithValue.

Comment: за примером можно и в [доку заглянуть](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Вот попробовал пример увы ошибка точно такая же.

Comment: `int.Parse(a);`

Comment: такая ошибка возникает и за неявного приведения типов.

Comment: Да я понимаю, что данная проблема из за приведения типов, но все равно ошибка остается и как ее победить я не знаю.

Comment: пробовал так SqlCommand command19 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO METHODNAME ( METHODID, DESCRIPTION, TEXTDESCRIPTION,METHODTYPEID) VALUES (cast (@a as SMALLINT), @b,@c,@d)",
                    connection);  Тоже не помогает

Comment: у меня Ваш код работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static void InsertMethodName(String connectionString, String[] values)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO METHODNAME(METHODID, DESCRIPTION, TEXTDESCRIPTION) VALUES(@a, @b, @c)";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", Int16.Parse(values[0]));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", values[1]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", values[2]);
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ваш комментарий, я нашел ошибку, и она была в строке подключения , есть еще одна идентичная база  с такой же таблицей, вот там возникает ошибка,,а так все нормально

Comment: я при работе использовал свою строку подключения, потому и не словил ошибку.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, ссылка не рабочая, но заголовок уже заинтриговал)

Comment: Это довольно известная статья, советую ознакомиться. Сайт что-то тормозит сейчас, открывается долго, но всё же открылся у меня.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, изчерпывающее обьяснение.